# It is possible to create proxy server on heroku?

Tags: heroku, proxy

I already tried to create a proxy server on heroku using java, python and nodejs but for some reason I can't.

I can only use port 80 so I would need to use the proxy as appname.herokuapp.com:80 but I get the response as "app doesn't exist".

Is this possible or not? Is there any alternative for what I want to do?

Answer (score 2):

The Heroku routing layer routes your http requests based on the `Host` header it finds in the HTTP request from your client. And if you have your own endpoint, it at least validates that the `Host` header content is one of your apps' domains.

If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38259076/1194456) you see that the `Host` header contains the name of the server you are trying to reach through the proxy server, not the proxy itself.

So there is no way you can run a http proxy server on heroku.