# req.url that does not belong to my domain

Tags: node.js, express, http

I got requests from china,

The problem is that the req.url does not belong to my domain

Usually it is `/` or `/login`, etc

Was I hacked?
I'd like to know a rationale for this

```js
const logger = function (req, res, next) {
    let { url, ip, method, statusCode } = req

    console.log(`${moment().format("L - hh:mm:ss")} `.red + `${method} `.green + `From: ` + `${ip?.replace("::ffff:", "")?.replace("::1", "localhost")} (${geoip.lookup(ip)?.country || "No IP"})`.cyan + ` : ` + `${req.user?.id || null} `.yellow + `At: ` + `${url} `.cyan)
    next()
}
app.use(logger)
```

[image]

Comment: You are probably under DOS attack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, somebody merely sent proxy requests to you. They are directed to your server but request a full URL instead of a path. Protocol-wise they'd look like `GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1` instead of just `GET / HTTP/1.1` as you are used to. If your server were (mis)configured to honor such requests as proxy, it'd send another request itself to `http://google.com/` and forward the response, but that doesn't happen in your case anyway so you can just ignore it.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38259076/1871033).

Comment: Does this lead to security problems and breaches? Can that be resolved?

Comment: You can't stop people from sending nonsense to your server. It's not a problem if your apps are configured properly.